# Is there a way to move Documents between 2 document libraries and preserve the original Modified,Created,Created by and modified by values

Tags: development, document-library, powershell, administration

I have the following inside my sharepoint On-premises Enterprise server 2013:-

- team site collection
- inside the team site i have created a sub-site.
- now both the root web and sub site have document library inside them.
- now we have added many documents inside the root web document library. and now i want to move these documents to be inside the sub-site's document library.. and i want to preserve the original values for the document such as :-

  - Modified
  - Created
  - Created by
  - modified by

so can anyone advice which approach i need to follow?

Comment: You could also use the PowerShell approach from this question.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83255/cant-see-items-in-site-content-and-structure-sharepoint-2010?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are within the same site collection, the Content and Structure page is available.  Go to the site settings page for the root and in the URL, replace "settings.aspx" with "sitemanager.aspx".  From this page you can move libraries between sites within the same site collection.  You can also move documents or items between containers that have the same column structure(content type).

Note:  The SharePoint Publishing Feature must be activated on the site collection for this to work.

Comment: now yes both libraries are within the same site collection, but on different subsites.. and both libraries are using the same built-in document library.. so will try your approach and update you shortly.. but should using the Content and Structure appraoch preserve the original metadata for the documents ??

Comment: Yes.  To verify, I just tested it on one of my sites.

Comment: but seems to be able to use the Content and Structure then i need to enable the publishing site collection feature,, otherwise the move will raise an exception .. although the sitemanager.aspx page will be accessible even when the publishing features are deactivated,, but the move will not work unless i enable atleast the publishing site collection feature...  is my test result correct, or i am missing something?

Comment: Nope.  That is all true.  You have to have that feature activated to move things this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the arrow on that document, under Send To there is an option to "Move" the document, a box pops up, and this will allow you to copy that document to another location and when the original is updated I believe it updates the copy too once it's checked in. You should always be able to look at previous versions of a document....That's the best option I can think of but there may be a better way.

Comment: your appraoch will not preserve the following values; 
    Modified
    Created
    Created by
    modified by